# How does Auth work with Firebase Preview Channels?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

Firebase recently announced preview channels: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/test-preview-deploy

But I'd like to know how that's supposed to work with apps that use firebase authentication (probably every app that uses firebase).

Right now it doesn't work since you have to add the URL to Authorized Domains and to the Oauth 2.0 Web client "Authorized JavaScript origins" in the Google Cloud console so you can actually login.

Comment: It sounds like you know what you need to do - add the authorized domain.  If you think this should be done automatically, that's a feature request that you should file with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support). Stack Overflow won't be able to help you with that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a feature request which is OT for SO.

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase CLI should automatically sync authorized domains when you deploy. You shouldn't need to add anything to your OAuth 2.0 web client unless you are dynamically setting the `authDomain` in your Firebase SDK config based on the current hostname (tip: don't do this!).

If you are deploying from a service account or user that doesn't have permission to modify Firebase Auth, it may be failing to sync. In this case you should see output along the lines of:

```
[hosting:channel] Unable to add channel domain to Firebase Auth.
```

If you don't see anything like that and you're on the latest version of the Firebase CLI and auth domains aren't syncing, please [file an issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues) on the Firebase CLI GitHub repo.